# How do I fix / use this basic crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I've been trying to use crontab for the first time today and have been struggling a lot. I want to run a simple script that basically just prints the current date and time in a terminal, and that went just fine, but getting it to consistently update has been very difficult for me (For example, getting the script to run every minute).

I tried using "crontab -e" and inserting "* * * * * /home/myUserName/Coding/Scripts/MyScript"

and making a copy of my script in cron.hourly to be safe because I'm a bit clueless. (And yes, I have tested the script itself manually and it works fine.)

Can anyone please help me? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You'd better add `/bin/sh` (or /bin/bash, or...) before the name of the script.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` is not attached to a terminal; it tends to mail its output to a user, usually `root` or the owner of the particular crontab.

Using `* * * * *` is probably not what you want -- if you want to run hourly, on the hour (minute zero) you would use `0 * * * *` to specify which minute you want to run, according to [man 5 crontab](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/)

The fields are `minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week` so the line I wrote says to run on minute zero, any hour, any day of the month, any month, any day of the week.